# google apps script to send recurring reminders doesn't work

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, gmail

I have a piece of code meant to send recurring emails every 8 weeks to a list of addresses in a google sheet. 
It does not seem to be sending out the mails.

I have tried various examples that I found online, with no success

```
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendEmails")
  .timeBased()
  .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY)
  .atHour(11)
  .nearMinute(00)
  .everyWeeks(8)
  .create();
function sendEmails() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("EMAILS") 
  var startRow = 2; 
  var numRows = sheet.getRange(1,4).getValue(); 
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2) 
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); 
   for (i in data) { 
    var row = data[i]; 
    var emailAddress = row[0];  
    var message = row[1]; 
    var subject = "mail subject here"; 
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message); 
  } 
}
```

when I run the script manually it seems to be working fine, so I guess the problem is in the new trigger part?

Comment: Check your project triggers - make sure they're set up as you're expecting. Also check for any failed executions of the script.

Comment: @ross I have no triggers, as I understand the first part of the code should be the trigger. None of the existing time triggers is suitable for my desired interval of 8 weeks (2 months).

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem:

Currently you have the code in place but it won't be used at all because it is not part of a function.

---

#### Requirement:

Trigger to run code every 8 weeks.

---

#### Solution:

Separate your trigger builder into a separate function.

Run the following script, it'll delete any triggers you may have accidentally set up and create a new one that should run as you're expecting.

```
function newTrigger() {
  //clear all triggers
  var tg = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  if(tg.length>0){
    for(i=0;i<tg.length;i++){
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(tg[i]);
    }
  }
  //build new trigger
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendEmails")
  .timeBased()
  .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY)
  .atHour(11)
  .nearMinute(00)
  .everyWeeks(8)
  .create();
}
```

---

#### Notes:

- You'll only need to run this function once to set up the trigger.
- In your project's triggers, it'll show as "every week" but should actually only run every 8 weeks like we specified in the code using `.everyWeeks(8)`.

---

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Class ClockTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder)

Comment: Sorry for being insecure... I should paste the code you wrote, followed by the whole code after function sendEmails() ?

Comment: The order doesn't matter, just run the function I provided once and your triggers should be fixed.